# Oracle-How to making an effect of ignoring condition

Tags: oracle, select

MY_FUN fucntion returns as expected.

```
SELECT MY_FUN('e1','m1','L1') TEST1 FROM DUAL; --This return value 5 as expected.

TEST1
-----
  5
```

Function parameters are, EQUIP,MODEL and LOT.
It select value in RR column in WC_BASE table 
according to EQUIP, MODEL and ITEM1.
And the ITEM1 value is found at table M_IF by LOT.

But,How to modify MY_FUN to return value even ITEM1 value is NULL?
For instance, LOT 'L3' is NULL or LOT4 not exist in M_IF Table.

```
--How to modify MY_FUN to return 6?  
SELECT MY_FUN('e1','m1','L3') TEST2 FROM DUAL; 
SELECT MY_FUN('e1','m1','L4') TEST3 FROM DUAL;
```

Expected result is

```
TEST2
------
   6
TEST3
------
   6
```

[My Table and data]

```
CREATE TABLE WC_BASE  (  
  EQUIP VARCHAR2(15),
  MODEL VARCHAR2(15),
  VAL VARCHAR2(15),
  ITEM1 VARCHAR2(15),
  RR VARCHAR2(15)
  );
CREATE TABLE M_IF  (  
  LOT VARCHAR2(15),
  ITEM1 VARCHAR2(15)
  );
 INSERT INTO WC_BASE VALUES('e1','m1','2','c1','5');  
 INSERT INTO WC_BASE VALUES('e1','m1','1',NULL,'6');  
 INSERT INTO M_IF VALUES('L1','c1');  
 INSERT INTO M_IF VALUES('L2','c1');
 INSERT INTO M_IF VALUES('L3',NULL);
```

[My Function]

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MY_FUN
(
  P1 IN VARCHAR2,
  P2 IN VARCHAR2, 
  P3 IN VARCHAR2     
 )
 RETURN NUMBER AS V_VALUE NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT (
---
WITH SG AS (SELECT * 
FROM WC_BASE
WHERE EQUIP =P1
AND MODEL =P2
AND ITEM1=(SELECT ITEM1 FROM M_IF WHERE LOT = P3) -- How to make an effect of ignoring this condition if the subquery returns null?
) 
SELECT (x1) ANSWER
      FROM ( SELECT 
            NVL(TO_NUMBER(RR),0)  AS x1
            FROM SG
            WHERE VAL IN (SELECT TO_CHAR(MAX(TO_NUMBER(VAL))) FROM SG )
        )
---
)
INTO V_VALUE
FROM DUAL ;
RETURN V_VALUE;
END MY_FUN;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `WITH` clause query using `OUTER JOIN`.

```
SELECT W.* 
FROM WC_BASE W
LEFT JOIN M_IF M
ON (W.ITEM1 = M.ITEM1) 
WHERE W.EQUIP =P1
AND W.MODEL =P2
AND M.LOT = P3
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I have tried your OUTER JOIN. But, the result of TEST2, TEST3 shows NULL